# Почему np.array() неверно просчитывает значение полинома?

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.array(6208)
y = x**5 + 2*x**4 + 7*x**3 + 14*x**2 + 3*x + 10
print(y)
# y = -9223185457808594742
```

```
x = 6208
y = x**5 + 2*x**4 + 7*x**3 + 14*x**2 + 3*x + 10
print(y)
# y = 9223558615900956874
```

Очевидно, что NumPy посчитал значение неверно, т.к значение данного полинома не может быть отрицательным. Предполагаю, что это из-за того, что `np.dtype("int64")` и не хватает памяти для просчета.

Но почему тогда **минус**? И как сделать так, чтобы `y` был просчитан правильно через `np.array`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552630/7485582

Comment: @КириллМалышев, в том ответе надо внимательно читать предупреждение - "This will get you a lot of Numpy array-like functionality __but few to none of the performance benefits.__" ;)

Comment: А всё же вам что нужно - абсолютная точность питоновского бесконечного `int` или быстрота фиксированных типов `numpy`? Нельзя одновременно получить и то и другое.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происходит переполнение для переменной типа `np.int64`. Допустимый диапазон значений можно проверить так:

```
In [46]: np.iinfo(x.dtype)
Out[46]: iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)
```

Можно явно указать тип данных - беззнаковое целое 64-бит:

```
In [47]: x = np.array(6208, dtype="uint64")

In [48]: y = x**5 + 2*x**4 + 7*x**3 + 14*x**2 + 3*x + 10

In [49]: print(f"{y:19.0f}")
9223558615900956672
```

Но и это не панацея для слишком больших значений:

```
In [50]: np.iinfo(x.dtype)
Out[50]: iinfo(min=0, max=18446744073709551615, dtype=uint64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю воспользоваться библиотекой [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html):

```
from sympy import Array

a = Array([6208])
y = a.applyfunc(lambda x: x**5 + 2*x**4 + 7*x**3 + 14*x**2 + 3*x + 10)
print(y)  # [9223558615900956874]
```

Однако я не проверял производительность такого подхода, поэтому не могу сказать, насколько это эффективно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я поправил. Там от версии питона или sympy это зависит.

Answer (score 1):

Полиномы в numpy лучше считать так:

```
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval
print(polyval(6208, [10,3,14,7,2,1]))
```

результат в np.float64:

```
9.223558615900957e+18
```

Answer (score -1):

Может быть потому, что np.array() ничего и не должен считать? Вы вообще в формулу полинома вставляете массив, вектор, чего вы вообще ожидали? С математической точки зрения это бессмыслица какая-то, x = np.array(6208) это не одно и то же, что x=6208

Comment: Ну вы бы попробовали код, прежде чем писать. `Numpy` умный, он понимает, что если с массивом из одного элемента обращаются как с числом, то результат должен быть число.